# How to backwards search in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, search, find, xcode4

I cannot figure out how I can use *reverse find* in Xcode 4. Back in Xcode 3 I simply used `CMD` + `F` and then `RETURN` to search forwards and `SHIFT` + `RETURN` to search backwards. The latter shortcut combinination is no longer working in Xcode 4, though. That suckz!
I am currently using Xcode 4.2.

Comment: I can't believe we're up to Xcode 4.6 now, and that bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Just FYI, works properly in 9.0 beta 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've found a match, use Command-G to find the next one, and Shift-Commmand-G to find the previous one. If you prefer some other shortcuts, feel free to modify the key bindings in Xcode's preferences. From the key bindings panel:

[image: Find commands and default shortcuts in Xcode]